# How can I split( a binary-containing string at a specific binary value?

Tags: javascript, split, binary

Overview:
  I'm building a Javascript tool inside a web page.  Except for loading that page, the tool will run without server communication.  A user will select a local file containing multiple binary records, each with a x'F0 start byte and x'F0 end byte.  The data in between is constrained to x'00 - x'7F and consists of:

- bit maps
- 1-byte numbers
- 2-byte numbers, low order byte first
- a smattering of ASCII characters

The records vary in lengths and use different formats.
[It's a set of MIDI Sysex messages, probably not relevant].
The local file is read via reader.readAsArrayBuffer and then processed thus:

```
var contents = event.target.result;
var bytes = new Uint8Array(contents);
var rawAccum = '';
for (x = 0; x < bytes.length; x++) { 
  rawAccum += bytes[x];
}
var records = rawAccum.split(/\xF0/g);
```

I expect this to split the string into an array of its constituent records, deleting the x'F0 start byte in the process.
It actually does very little. records.length is 1 and records[0] contains the entire input stream.

[The actual split code is: var records = rawAccum.split(/\xF0\x00\x00\x26\x02/g); which should remove several identical bytes from the start of each record.  When this failed I tried the abbreviated version above, with identical (non)results.]

I've looked at the doc on split( and at several explanations of \xXX among regex references.  Clearly something does not work as I have deduced.  My experience with JavaScript is minimal and sporadic.

How can I split a string of binary data at the occurrence of a specific binary byte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splitting appears to work correctly:

```
var rawAccum = "\xf0a\xf0b\xf0c\xf0"
console.log( rawAccum.length);       // 7
var records = rawAccum.split(/\xF0/g);
console.log(records);                // "", "a", "b", "c", ""
```

but the conversion of the array buffer to a string looks suspicious. Try converting the unsigned byte value to a string before appending it to `rawAccum`:

```
for (x = 0; x < bytes.length; x++) { 
    rawAccum += String.fromCharCode( bytes[x]);
}
```

---

**Data conversions** (*update after comment*)

The filereader reads the file into an array buffer in memory, but  JavaScript does not provide access to array buffers directly. You can either create and initialize a typed array from the buffer (e.g. using the Uint8Array constructor as in the post), or access bytes in the buffer using a [`DataView` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView). Methods of `DataView` objects can convert sequences of bytes at specified positions to integers of varying types, such as the 16 bit integers in the Midi sysex records.

JavaScript strings use sequences of 16 bit values to hold characters, where each character uses one or two 16 bit values encoded using UTF-16 character encoding. 8 bit characters use only the lower 8 bits of a single 16 bit value to store their Unicode code point.

It is possible to convert an array buffer of octet values into a "binary string", by storing each byte value from the buffer in the low order bits of a 16 bit character and appending it to an existing string. This is what the post attempts to do. But in JavaScript strings (and individual characters which have a string length of 1)  are not a subset of integer numbers and have their own data type, "string".

So to convert an unsigned 8 bit number to a JavaScript 16 bit character of type "string", use the `fromCharCode` static method of the global `String` object, as in

```
rawAccum += String.fromCharCode( bytes[x]);
```

Calling `String.fromCharCode` is also how to convert an ASCII character code located within MIDI data to a character in JavaScript.

To convert a binary string character derived from an 8 bit value  back into  a number, use the String instance method `charCodeAt` on a string value and provide the character position:

```
var byteValue = "\xf0".charCodeAt(0);
```

returns the number 0xf0 or 250 decimal.

If you append a number to a string, as in the question, the number is implicitly converted to a decimal string representation of its value first:

```
"" + 0xf0 + 66 // becomes the string "24066"
```

---

Note that an array buffer can be inspected using a Uint8Array created from it, sliced into pieces using the buffer's `slice` method and have integers of various types extracted from the buffer using data views. Please review if creating a binary string remains the best way to extract and interpret Midi record contents.

Comment: Your suspicion seems to be warranted and your suggestion works.

In both the original and with your modification, rawAccum is type string.  I surmise that I'm dealing with 'dynamic type conversion'.  Is that correct?